# JS for DIV structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightgallery

I am using the following code to call JS function for mentioned DIV #lightGallery

```
 $("#lightGallery").lightGallery({
    thumbnail: false,
});
```

I need modifing JS code to make function be called for any #DIV+num like #lightGallery1, #lightGallery2,...etc

Comment: And so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, use attribute-starts-with selector for the `id`:

```
$("[id^=lightGallery]").lightGallery({
    thumbnail: false,
});
```

If you need to filter out other elements whose `id` begins with `lightGallery`, but follow with non-numeric characters, you can also use `filter()`:

```
$("[id^=lightGallery]").filter(function(){
    return /^lightGallery\d+/.test(this.id);
}).lightGallery({
    thumbnail: false,
});
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^=value]`) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[id^="lightGallery"]').lightGallery({
    thumbnail: false,
});
```

Comment: Even though OP is wanting to get the elements this way I really think he should be getting them by class rather than Id.

Comment: Yes, that is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this, I would simply give the elements a class Name and call all of them with

```
$('.lightGallery').lightGallery({
    thumbnail: false,
});
```

Comment: This is a better way to do this. You grab by Id when you just want 1 element, you grab by class when you want multiple elements.